# Display an animated PNG image to my layout in android using XML

Tags: android, xml, image

Can XML be used for displaying an animated image in my android layout?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="82dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:id="@+id/splashSpinner"/>
```

Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__000" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__001" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__002" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__003" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__004" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__005" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__006" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__007" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__008" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__009" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__010" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim__011" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

JAVA

```
    this.spinner = this.view.findViewById(R.id.splashSpinner);

    this.spinner.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            AnimationDrawable spinnerAnim = (AnimationDrawable) spinner.getBackground();
            if (!spinnerAnim.isRunning())
            {
                spinnerAnim.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know that but i need to play a GIF file.

Comment: You're not talking about gif in your question... It is not possible to add a gif in an android project.

Comment: Easy take your animated gif and open in adobe photoshop. it will show you all the layers. save each layer as a png file. then use the example in this response to animate the pngs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to animate the image in your xml from the code. You can get the reference to the png image and animate manually.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have one image, to be precise "Balloon" image. I need to create some 600 images of this and then animate randomly on the screen. I am able to animate but it uses approximately some 300Mb of RAM. is there a standard optimized way to do this?