# Using a single view for multiple animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following [animation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_tVPBZ7u9adVusktaUfCLoB0ADtP0BSY). Here it show 4 circles simultaneously.

I tried it using multiple views. Like two imageview one on other and applied zoom in and out and translationy animation.

But I want to know If it is possible with single view. If yes then how ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `"If yes then how ?"` - read about [custom views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you create an Animation Drawable with different frames inside it. Then you can set this drawable as an image resource and start/stop animation.

All you need is different frames of your animation. You can do that by using some tools available online. 
One of which is https://ezgif.com/split

Refer this for animation drawable:

[Display an animated PNG image to my layout in android using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080024/display-an-animated-png-image-to-my-layout-in-android-using-xml)

All the best!

Comment: Hey, if my answer helped you, kindly upvote. Thank you for accepting it :)